# How to copy and paste a string with imbalanced quotation marks?

Tags: r, string, quotes, double-quotes

Consider the following text

> Today is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's target

If I copy and paste this text and I try to put it into a variable, like this:

```
mystring = "Today is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's target"
```

that will not work because the quotation marks are imbalanced.

Is there a simple solution? How can I copy and paste this text to my R script?

Comment: like enclosing within `''` ? does not work for me

Comment: `> mytext<- 'Today is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's target'
Error: unexpected symbol in "mytext<- 'Today is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's"`

Comment: Sorry, I missed you have `year's` with a quote.

Comment: :-) that is the issue here

Comment: haha sure thing, but the issue is that I copy and paste a HUGE text from the internet. so doing that manually is not possible

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't copy it manually, but scrape the webpage with `rvest` for example.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting it manually? If so you could find + replace (") with (\").

Comment: Try `readClipboard()` or paste it in a text file and try `readLines()`

Comment: @Jaap good idea but my firewall prevents me from using `rvest`

Comment: @StephenWitkowski maybe this is the most fool-proof solution. I would post that. thanks!

Comment: @d.b hey what is this `readClipboard` madness???? :)

Comment: I would recommend against readClipboard - you don't want the outcome of your code to be dependent on your OS state every time you run. If you have a HUGE text the text file approach is probably the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Text to cop**y

```
Today is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's target.
Yesterday is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's target's sum.
```

**Read into R**

```
x = readLines("clipboard")
#Warning message:
#In readLines("clipboard") : incomplete final line found on 'clipboard'
```

**Convert to `data.frame`**

```
data.frame(x)                                                                             
#                                                                        x
#1           Today is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's target.
#2 Yesterday is the day "Stack Overflow" will miss its year's target's sum.
```

**Instead of `"clipboard"`, you could also paste the copied text in a file and use `readLines` with it.**